# Github actions schedule issue

Tags: github, cron, cicd

I`m trying to run cron for each branches but have a problem that cron work only on dev branche: This is my settings:`

```
name: E2E Tests

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 5 * * *"

  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev
      - stg
      - master`
```

I was trying a lot of changes but did not succeed with it. I had create separate file,deleted  dependencies on branch and nothing...